# Spotfire Add Data Table as only String

Tags: string, addition, spotfire

I was wondering if it is possible to set Spotfire to import all columns automatically as string and then make changes during the import, my job entails importing lots of files and Spotfire allocates what it considers to be the best type but I need all as string apart from Real and Date so if I could set it to string and then change the few it would help speed things up

Answer (score 1):

there is no feature to disable Spotfire's data type detection.

as an aside, different data types are stored in memory in different ways. string is probably the least efficient.

I can't think of a disadvantage of letting Spotfire set the data type automatically (assuming it's correctly identifying the data type) so it's very unclear why you'd want to do this.